# Netbeans IDE ajax request POST warning jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, netbeans

```
Do not Access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly.

Use some filtering functions instead (e.g. filter_input(), conditions with is_*() functions, etc.).
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

I am getting this kind of warning in my NetBeans IDE when I am sending an AJAX request to my PHP file.

My request type is `POST` and when I go to PHP page I am getting the warning.

Can this warning harm my code in any way. How do I get rid of this? 
Should I just ignore it or it very important to get rid of the warning?

The warning is appearing in the `$_POST` when I am getting the data that is passed from AJAX.

Example:

```
$fname = ($_POST['Fname']);
```

The line `$_POST` is having the yellow underline.

Comment: It is just a warning, suggesting best practices. It will not affect your code. Accessing superglobals directly is considered not secure

Comment: @B-and-P how do i best deal with it then?all i know to access POST from ajax request is like that can you give me another way?the safer one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning text you posted gives you the examples - pass your `$_POST` param through a function like `filter_input()` or `is_*()`.

try something like:

```
$fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Fname', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Reference - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

**EDIT:**
The list of available filters is linked on the function page.
You do not have to use `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`, I just gave it as example.

The point is that Netbeans telling you to validate / sanitize POST data. You can write your own functions for that. Check whether the value is of correct type, length etc.

Comment: if i want to include `'s` in the name or `-` to connect text or `&` and `$` do need to filter?i cant understand this line `Equivalent to calling htmlspecialchars() ` very much from the link of the one you gave me. There will be instance for me to put the special chars what type should i use?

Comment: @HogRider see my edit above. The Netbeans just encourages you to validate your POST data and not use it as is, blindly, which is a potencial security risk. I, personally, develop a lot of intranet applications that are not open to the web and, in such cases, I do not bother with POST sanitizing at all (i.e. ignore these warnings)

Comment: i am also trying to run this locally i mean in local network only but practicing good programming does not hurt would it?appreciated the explanation happy coding

Comment: @HogRider No, it definitely wouldn't hurt! Cheers!